# Почему нет записи в google-аналитике, хотя ошибок в консоли нет?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, аналитика

Вставляю вот этот скрипт для google-аналитики:

```js
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю цель:

```
 ga('send', 'event', 'cat', 'oper');
```

Срабатывает она должна на кнопку. Никаких ошибок в консолb не наблюдается, клик выполняется и функция ga запускается. Но никаких записей в google-аналитике нет.

Comment: Немного глупый вопрос, но мало ли... А вы вместо  `UA-XXXXXXX-1` свой код указали?

Comment: Да, свой указал

Comment: Цели, которые для URL ставятся работают нормально. А вот с событиями проблема какая-та...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [отладочную версию](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging?hl=ru) Google Analytics, возможно она вам даст больше информации о возникшей проблеме.

Comment: Попробовал. Все отправляется. Ошибок в консоле нет. Штука в том, что в отчетах в режиме реального времени на вкладке События все отображается. А вот когда я перехожу во вкладку Конверсия > Цели > Обзор, там пусто... События и цели в ГА это вообще разные штуки или нет? Если да, то как настроить именно цели, а не события?